# Google Wallet / Android Pay integration in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, android-pay

I have Xamarin project targeting both Android and iOS platforms using Xamarin.Forms. I searched but I can't find an answer or any information about that.

Is there any way I can integrate Google Wallet / Android Pay in my project and what are my options.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Android Pay APIs, but I imagine you could utilize them using the DependencyService.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out or find any documentation?  I am looking for the same thing.  Thanks

Answer (score -1):

can't you use Xamarin.InAppBillin

check this [enter link description here](https://components.xamarin.com/view/xamarin.inappbilling)